# ionic framework: How to detect visible ion-item's inside ion-list?

Tags: ionic-framework

```
<ion-header-bar>
  Showing at {{distance.current_scroll_distance}}
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item collection-repeat='results in data.results'>
    {{result.name}} / {{result.distance}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

I need to detect scroll on the ion list, and then determine which is the first visible ion-item, to update current_scroll_distance on headbar.

help will be appreciated.

Comment: I need to check which is the first visible ion-item everytime the user scrolls over the ion list, not on items click, to update the headbar while the user is scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand referred to "Which is the first visible ion-item"?

Remember that each ng-repeat there is a `$ index`! and that is as a counter of the elements, if you want to identify the first, just to see `$ index == 0`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call an event, whichever you need, and then capture the $index for example using ng-click:

```
<ion-header-bar>
  Showing at {{distance.current_scroll_distance}}
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item collection-repeat='results in data.results'>
    <div ng-click="captureElemnt($index)">{{result.name}} / {{result.distance}}</div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

js:

```
$scope.captureElement = function(index){

  if (index == 0){

   //do whatever you need

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not exactly what i want.

Comment: I need to check which is the first visible ion-item everytime the user scrolls over the ion list, to update the headbar while the user is scrolling.